# Printing Double Linked List in button

Tags: c#, linked-list, nodes, doubly-linked-list

Trying to print a double linked list in C#, having some trouble with it and was wondering if someone can help me figure out where I went wrong and how to use this print method in a button.

Here is my Print method

```
public void PrintNodes(LinkedList<Transaction> values)
        {
            if (values.Count != 0)
            {
                Output += "Here are your transaction details:";

                foreach (Transaction t in values)
                {
                    Output += "\r\n" + t;
                }
                Output += "\r\n";
            }
            else
            {
                Output += "The Doubly Linked List is empty!";
            }
        }
```

and here is the rest of the code

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
    SqlConnection conn;
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    class Transaction
    {
        SqlConnection conn;
        //variables of the Book Table created
        public int AccountNo;
        public DateTime Date;
        public string Description;
        public string DebitCredit;
        public Double Amount;
        public Transaction(int ACCNo, DateTime TimeDate, string description, string CreditDebit, double amount)
        //constructor
        {
            this.AccountNo = ACCNo;
            this.Date = TimeDate;
            this.Description = description;
            this.DebitCredit = CreditDebit;
            this.Amount = amount;
        }
        public void FillText()
        {
            LinkedList<Transaction> Transactions = new LinkedList<Transaction>(); //create the generic linked list

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("dbConnection1"); //Connection string

            int AccountNo = Int32.Parse(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Please enter account number", "Account Number")); //Prompt the user for account number


            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * From Transactions where AccountNo = " + AccountNo, conn); //command to execute
            conn.Open();  //open the connection to the database           
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();


            if (reader.HasRows)//Check if the table has records
            {
                while (reader.Read()) //read all records with the given AccountNo
                {
                    Transaction Transaction001 = new Transaction(reader.GetInt32(0), reader.GetDateTime(1), reader.GetString(2), reader.GetString(3), reader.GetDouble(4)); //New Transaction node
                    Transactions.AddFirst(Transaction001);// add the node to the Doubly Linked List (Transactions)
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No records found");
            }

            PrintNodes(Transactions);

            reader.Close();
            conn.Close();
        }
        public string Output;
        //This is where the print node is

   }
private void btnExecute_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Any assistance would be appreciated, as I am pretty confident that the connection will work but I for some reason cannot figure out how to get this printed to test it. It is probably a very simple thing that for some reason I am missing and I am just having a brain fart, but any help would be appreciated. I am not a professional or student, just someone who is playing around with C# and trying to get a grasp of it. Also if you spot any problems with the Print method could you let me know.

Comment: Can you describe the error you see?

Comment: Sorry for stupid question, but did you forget to add code into the button click event handler (btnExecute_Click)? Something like 'var transaction = new Transaction(); transaction.FillText();'.

Comment: Is `Output` a string? And do you want to print in a console? in a textbox? actual print to paper?